# Using Apache/ mod_proxy_ajp/ APEX Listener together

Tags: oracle

Our application is developed with APEX, and it is accessed through APEX listener through HTTP on default port 8080. Now, we want to switch to Apache with mod_proxy_ajp and reconfigure APEX listener to use AJP. We tryed to simply add -Dapex.ajp=8009 to startup parameters but we get 500 Internal server error on apache.

This is how APEX was started with HTTP listener:

```
java -Dapex.home=/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime \
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 \
    -jar /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/apex.war
```

This is logs of that startup:

```
INFO: Starting: /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/apex.war
 See: 'java -jar apex.war --help' for full range of configuration options

INFO: Extracting to: /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime

INFO: Using classpath: file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/____embedded/start.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/ucp.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/ojmisc.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/apex.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/xmlparserv2-11.2.0.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/je-4.0.103.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/xdb-11.2.0.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/poi-3.6-20091214.jar:

INFO: Starting Embedded Web Container in: /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime

23.02.2012 17:26:13 ____bootstrap.Deployer deploy
INFO: Will deploy application path=/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/web.xml
23.02.2012 17:26:13 ____bootstrap.Deployer deploy
INFO: deployed application path=/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/web.xml
Using config file: /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex-config.xml
-- listing properties --

PropertyCheckInterval=60

ValidateConnection=true

MinLimit=1

MaxLimit=10

InitialLimit=3

AbandonedConnectionTimeout=900

MaxStatementsLimit=10

InactivityTimeout=1800

MaxConnectionReuseCount=1000

APEX Listener version : 1.1.3.243.11.40

APEX Listener server info: Grizzly/1.9.18-o

23.02.2012 17:26:34 com.sun.grizzly.Controller logVersion
INFO: Starting Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o - Thu Feb 23 17:26:34 UZT 2012
INFO: http://localhost:8080/apex started.
```

Now, we add -Dapex.ajp=8009 parameter and restart APEX listener:

```
apex: client (pid 19896) exited with 143 status
INFO: Starting: /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/apex.war
 See: 'java -jar apex.war --help' for full range of configuration options

INFO: Extracting to: /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime

INFO: Using classpath: file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/____embedded/start.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/ucp.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/ojmisc.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/apex.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/xmlparserv2-11.2.0.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/je-4.0.103.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/xdb-11.2.0.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:file:/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/lib/poi-3.6-20091214.jar:

INFO: Starting Embedded Web Container in: /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime

23.02.2012 17:30:53 ____bootstrap.Deployer start
INFO: AJP Listener on port 8009 enabled, HTTP listener is disabled.
23.02.2012 17:30:53 ____bootstrap.Deployer deploy
INFO: Will deploy application path=/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/web.xml
23.02.2012 17:30:53 ____bootstrap.Deployer deploy
INFO: deployed application path=/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/listener/runtime/apex/WEB-INF/web.xml
23.02.2012 17:30:53 com.sun.grizzly.http.jk.server.JkMain init
INFO: Can't find home, jk2.properties not loaded
23.02.2012 17:30:53 com.sun.grizzly.http.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
23.02.2012 17:30:53 com.sun.grizzly.http.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=3/15  config=null
```

When trying to access some page through Apache we get 500 Internal server error and following exception in APEX listener logs:

```
23.02.2012 17:31:54 com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter doService
SEVERE: service exception:
oracle.dbtools.rt.service.ServiceLocatorException: There are no services defined
#011at oracle.dbtools.rt.service.ServiceLocator.acquireAll(ServiceLocator.java:91)
#011at oracle.dbtools.rt.service.ServiceLocator.acquire(ServiceLocator.java:74)
#011at oracle.dbtools.rt.service.ServiceLocator.acquire(ServiceLocator.java:85)
#011at oracle.dbtools.rt.web.HttpEndpointBase.dispatchers(HttpEndpointBase.java:138)
#011at oracle.dbtools.rt.web.HttpEndpointBase.service(HttpEndpointBase.java:85)
#011at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
#011at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:195)
#011at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.FilterChainImpl.invokeFilterChain(FilterChainImpl.java:139)
#011at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.doService(ServletAdapter.java:376)
#011at ____bootstrap.SecureServletAdapter.doService(SecureServletAdapter.java:72)
#011at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:324)
#011at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
#011at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapterChain.service(GrizzlyAdapterChain.java:180)
#011at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
#011at com.sun.grizzly.http.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:237)
#011at com.sun.grizzly.http.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:330)
#011at com.sun.grizzly.http.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:816)
#011at com.sun.grizzly.http.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:742)
#011at com.sun.grizzly.http.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:942)
#011at com.sun.grizzly.http.jk.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:666)
#011at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

I assume Apache configuration is correct:

```
    ProxyPass /apex/ ajp://localhost:8009/apex/
    ProxyPassReverse /apex/ ajp://localhost:8009/apex/
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Most likely you are using OpenJDK, try using Oracle Sun JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the apex listener can't find it's configuration file. 
Start it up again in http mode, specifying where the application should deploy to  with the "-Dapex.home=" parameter.

navigate to

http://:8080/apex/listenerAdmin and complete configuration again, 
The config file will save to the directory above, and will be read from there
everytime it starts up.

I have the listener running with ajp using mod_proxy_ajp without problems here.